# Ignore file extensions when doing a diff between directories with Meld

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, meld

Is there a way to set Meld to ignore file extensions when diffing two directories?

The directories I want to diff are two versions of a directory in my Mercurial repo but since the earlier version, the file extensions have been changed from .c to .cpp. As each .cpp file appears as new while the .c file have been removed, I can't diff the files directly in that view - each simply will open in its own tab.

I can open the previous version in Meld via tortoisehg and then add the second file manually by browsing to it (this requires the working directory is updated to the later version). Is there instead a more direct way to simply select a file from either directory to diff between when in the directory diff view?

Any help would be much appreciated.